# Node-sass, node-gyp errors npm install error python 3.7 default env in debian linux_x64

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-sass

When I try to npm install wetty project, getting Node-sass, node-gyp errors.

my default python is 3.7 in debian linux_x64.

```
root@abc-host:/home/wetty# npm install node-sass

> node-sass@4.12.0 install /home/wetty/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /root/.npm/node-sass/4.12.0/linux-x64-64_binding.node

> node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall /home/wetty/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/wetty/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Testing binary
Bus error (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 135
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 135
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-21T02_00_20_069Z-debug.log
root@abc-host:/home/wetty#
```